# AVCaptureStillImageOutput Missing Metadata

Tags: objective-c, exif, avcapturesession

I use the following code to capture the image:

```
[self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
     CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment(imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
     NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
     UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
     NSDictionary *metadata = (__bridge NSDictionary*)exifAttachments;
     NSLog(@"%@",metadata");
}];
```

and here is the logged output:

```
ApertureValue = "2.526068811667588";
BrightnessValue = "-0.5270684580355165";
ExposureMode = 0;
ExposureProgram = 2;
ExposureTime = "0.06666666666666667";
FNumber = "2.4";
Flash = 16;
FocalLenIn35mmFilm = 35;
FocalLength = "4.28";
ISOSpeedRatings =     (
    500
);
MeteringMode = 5;
PixelXDimension = 3264;
PixelYDimension = 2448;
SceneType = 1;
SensingMethod = 2;
ShutterSpeedValue = "3.906905022631062";
SubjectArea =     (
    1631,
    1223,
    881,
    881
);
WhiteBalance = 0;
```

Why am I not getting any time related metadata? I want to find out when the image was taken.

Comment: Do I need to add the "kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal" value myself? Seems kinda counterintuitive...

Answer (score 0):

I determined that the date and time is added to the metadata after it has been added to the Camera Roll (without any work on the developers part). No need to worry about the info missing!